# Why is the CPU % sort indicator backwards in System Monitor application?

Tags: system-monitor

My system is 14.04 and when I open the System Monitor application then click on the % CPU header the sort indicator is opposite. When the wide end is on top, lower utilization process are shown first and when the wide end is on the bottom the high utilization processes are shown at top. What would cause this?

Edit: My 12.04 install sort the way I see as correct - when the fat part is on the top the high utilization processes are at the top.

Comment: Same on 16.04. I am not really annoyed by that though, in fact, I never actually paid attention to the direction of that arrow.

Comment: Sounds normal to me.  When pointing down, it's ascending, so from 0->100.  When pointing up, it's descending from 100->0.  The wide end is where it'll start at zero.

Comment: I have a 12.04 install that works the opposite of how I described.

Answer (score 0):

The arrow indicates the direction of the sort, starting with zero.

If the arrow points down, it'll start from 0 and go up as you go down the list.

If the arrow points up, it'll start from the highest and work its way to zero.  Or another way of thinking of it is that it'll start from the bottom at zero and work its way up.

Comment: I have a 12.04 install that works the opposite of how I described.

Comment: I imagine they changed the sort order to something that makes more sense.  The arrow pointing from 0-100 regardless of orientation makes more sense than if it were backwards.  It's a way of thinking that's different, it's been blogged about http://notes.ericjiang.com/posts/456